# How to solve the below code!? Armstrong number between given intervals in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Need solution for python code!

How can we find the armstrong numbers in given interval.

I have written the code successfuly to identify the number, but could not be able to get the desired output.

**My code :**

```
lower = int(input())  
upper = int(input())  
  
for num in range(lower,upper + 1):  
    sum = 0  
    temp = num
    armstrong = ""
    while temp > 0:  
        digit = temp % 10  
        sum += digit ** 3
        temp //= 10 
        if num == sum:  
            armstrong = armstrong + (str(num) + " ")
            print(armstrong)
```

**Case - 1**
Input :
150
200

Expected out put :
153
This case was successful.

**Case - 2:**
Input :
1
3

Expected output :
1 2 3
Could not get the proper output for this one!

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written only works for numbers between 100 and 999 because of line:

```
sum += digit ** 3
```